# is it possible to query the python package dependencies tree quickly

Tags: python-3.x

I am facing a python package conflict, package A need h2 version > 3.0 < 4.0, package B need h2 version > 4.0, now I want to downgrade package B to solve this conflict problem. But right now, I did not know which version should I downgrade, one way is to downgrade the package B one by one still found the package dependencies less than 4.0. Is there any better way to know which of package B dependencies h2 less than 4.0?

Comment: Some tools like poetry will do proper dependency resolution for you - but "quickly" is n not an appropriate description of any that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the version to let pip auto handle the version dependencies. But  I still like the version to fixed because I the automatic version may changed silently that cause another problem. in the requirement.txt may look like this:

```
selenium-wire
scrapy
```

so we did not need to concern about which version should use.